# Why are measurements and calculations of atomic radii so different?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics

On Wikipedia, the 'empirically-measured atomic radius' is smaller for most of the elements on the 'atomic radius' page than it is on the pages of the individual elements.  Why?

The measurements on the atomic-radius page were done by John Slater a long time ago...... But the 'calculated' radii are even larger than Slater's, let alone the presumably newer empirical measurements on each element's wiki page, so theory and experiment are growing further and further apart?  Why?

Also, some elements like iron have a 'high-spin' covalent radius measured.  When does that apply?  I thought almost all molecules were in a singlet state?

P.S. I am sorry that I cross-posted....

But, does anybody have an answer?  Or a link to an explanation?

Comment: One thing to watch out for in this kind of business is reports using different definitions of the radius. This comes up in the context of proton radii, as well. The theoretically convenient metrics are different from the experimentally convenient ones.

Comment: Nearly identical question asked over on Chemistry: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117367/why-are-atomic-radii-calculations-all-over-the-map. Please don't cross-post.